# Make a List observable

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

I wrote the following Extension-Method:

```
 /// <summary>
    /// make a Enumerable observable
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="enumerable"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<T>(enumerable);
    }
```

This method works so far. Now I have a converter returning a IList (see datagrid.SelectedItems):

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WOLF_APP.ViewModel
{
    public class SelectionChangedConverter : IEventArgsConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, object parameter)
        {
            var dataGrid = parameter as DataGrid;

            return dataGrid.SelectedItems;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object   parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

In my ViewModel I want to pass the converterted IList to a ObservableCollection using the extension method.

```
 private RelayCommand<IList<object>> _fileSelectionChanged;
    public RelayCommand<IList<object>> FileSelectionChanged
    {
        get
        {
            if (_fileSelectionChanged == null)
            {
                _fileSelectionChanged = new RelayCommand<IList<object>>(
                    items =>
                    {
                        SelectedFiles = items.ToObservableCollection<FileInfo>();                            

                    }
                );
            }

            return _fileSelectionChanged;
        }
    }
```

I am getting a compiler-error telling me that the extension method expects an IEnumerable. Doesn't IList implement the IEnumerable Interface?
**What is my mistake?**

Comment: Can you post the exact error?

Comment: what is the type of SelectedFiles ? Because you do call extension methods on List<T> when it is defined for IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @Blake : I have a german version, but here is a translation of the error:   "IList<object>" does not contain a Definition for "ToObservableCollection", an the overload of the extension method "ExtensionMethods.ToObservableCollection<FileInfo>(IEnumerable<FileInfo>)" requires a receiver of tye "IEnumerable<FileInfo>".

Comment: @Rahul: SelectedFiles is of type ObservableCollection<FileInfo>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the fact that the compiler is expecting items of type `FileInfo` but your IList contains `object`s.

I put some of your code into VS and the error in English is...

> 'IList<object>' does not contain a definition for 'ToObservableCollection' and the best extension method overload 'Extensions.ToObservableCollection<FileInfo>(IEnumerable<FileInfo>)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable<FileInfo>'

This is saying that the closest extension method it could find is the one you wrote, but the type being passed to it is not right.
To fix this we just need to cast your `object`s to `FileInfo`s.

Here's one way to do that (assuming your objects were originally create as FileInfos).

```
items.Cast<FileInfo>().ToObservableCollection()
```

Comment: Thats exactly the cause. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ThomasLucas: If you know *for sure* that *every* member of the list is `FileInfo` then use `Cast<FileInfo>` -- but if you already know that, then why is it not a `IList<FileInfo>` in the first place?  If you do not know that for sure then use `OfType<FileInfo>` which will filter the non-fileinfo objects out of the list.

Comment: @EricLippert: the object comes from the **SelectionChangedConverter** . I use the converter to pass selected items in a **dataGrid** to my ViewModel via a EventToCommand trigger. By changing the generic oject to FileInfo I would be limited to dataGrids containing FileInfo Objects., That way I can reuse the controller for other dataGrids in my UI. Certainly there is a way to refactor the controler for other UI-Controls.